# Unique Identifier(Integer ID) for llvm::instruction across different run

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

Is there anything in the llvm::Instruction class that can be used as a unique identifier for it across different execution instances? I cannot use llvm::Instruction* as it changes for different execution instances.

Comment: No. Instruction is optimized for size, as there are very many of them.

Comment: If you are using the same LLVM IR input file each time, you could use the name assigned to a value?

Comment: If the IR doesn't change, then you can use "an address" of the instruction in the form of "function name" + "basic block index" + "instruction index". That worked for us pretty well. But beware, it may break if the IR is modified.

Comment: @AlexDenisov Thanks, that what I was thinking as a possible solution. but I'm still amazed as to why something so basic is not present in the llvm::Instruction itself.

Comment: The reason it is not present is probably that llvm nodes form a graph and so you'd have to do an O(n) traversal to compute it, I think